# Select a picture from asset folders in Android

Tags: android

I want the user to be able to select a picture from a given set of pictures that come with my app.

Is it possible to use `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)` but not with media files on the phone of the user, but with some pictures/bitmaps I defined earlier? So far I only found examples to pick images from the gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, there is no `ACTION_PICK` that will pick images from your project's `assets/` folder. You would need to create your own UI for that.

Answer (score 0):

No.Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK) choose picture from Gallery in your phone.

```
   private static final int SELECT_PHOTOS = 100;
   Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
  photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
  startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTOS);
```

For asset folder [Check this](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/)

```
 try 
 {
// get input stream
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("avatar.jpg");
// load image as Drawable
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
// set image to ImageView
mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
 }
catch(IOException ex) 
{
return;
 }
```